# How to incorporate Angular routes with ZF2?

Tags: php, angularjs, zend-framework2

I am putting together a ZF2+Angular application but I am not sure the best way to incorporate ZF2 routes with Angular routes.

Should I keep one main route to do the ng-view then call from there the angular routes? If so, how should I define the ZF2 routes so it will work with Angular routing and not be looking for ZF2 controllers and actions?

UPDATE: I did not fully understand AngularJs routes before I posted this. You are correct, they are different ZF2 != Angular routes..of course.

In order to get this working in a hybrid environment I needed to realize that Angular is more for a single page app SPA, so having my ZF2 taking me to a general page, where the SPA routes can be applied from there is the solution.

app/login <- zf route.. 
- calls app/api/login (zf route) from angular and redirects to
app/main <- zf route for the main application
app/main/#angular-route <- an angular route inside the main zf route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular = **Frontend**, ZF2 = **Backend**.

These two only play together in a way that Angular will call routes of ZF2 to fill angulars views with some data. Angular routes and ZF2 routes have no common ground.

Comment: I agree and I understand... But if my app.local/route1 is to load a partial from Angular, I do not want ZF@ to interpret it as a Controller=Index, Action=route1...

I have my Angular app in the /public of the ZF2 app doing REST requests to itself. 

So how to separate app.local/route1 from ZF2 to Angular?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, all angular routes are behind the sharp.. `domain.loc/#route1`

Comment: Using Html5mode set to true you don't need the #. @smorhaim, correct if I'm mistaking, is that your problem when an Angular page is refreshed you get the 404 response from your ZF2 app?